# PHP - how do I get top ten records from database by highest to lowest

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, charts

I've searched everywhere including Stackoverflow for my answer and couldn't find the exact information's I was looking for. Like I've tried those answer's in other sites and some answer's here at StackOverFlow and it didn't work.

The problem is that I am working on a project where displaying the highest reputation by top ten (aka: "Leaderboards/Charts") but keep getting low (first) and then random (eg: low, high, low, medium) based on reputation. It's weird, I'm not experienced in SQLi commands, so call me a noob (I'll accept).

Here's the code I have currently written that doesn't work:

```
<h1>Leaderboards</h1>
<?php
$query = "SELECT user_name, reputation FROM m_users ORDER BY reputation DESC LIMIT 10";
?>
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            top ten
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <div class="table-responsive">
                                <table class="table">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>User</th>
                                            <th>Reputation Points</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
<?php
foreach($mysqli->query($query) as $rep)
{
    echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>';
            echo ''.$rep['user_name'].'';
        echo '</td>';
        echo '<td>';
            echo $rep['reputation'];
        echo '</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
?>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

The results that comes up is:

```
jay 100
ray 1000
joy 250
```

What I want is: "Highest to Lowest" (simple chart/leaderboard), like for example: "In some online gaming multiplayer like Call of Duty, it shows the highest to lowest by scores...etc". This just results in lowest, highest, lowest, medium...etc.

I can't fix this at all, can anyone help me detect the bug? :(

Comment: If you execute your MySQL query, what´s your result??

Comment: it shows = jay [100], ray = [1000] & joy = [250]. It's not in order, it should be highest to lowest but weirdly showing low to high :/ :(

Comment: Hi, I think you must have the `reputation` column as a varchar type and not int. That's why you have sorted in that way, "100" -> "1000" -> "250". You should change the variable type in the reputation column to integer. See if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```
SELECT `user_name`, `reputation` FROM `m_users` ORDER BY convert(`reputation`, UNSIGNED INTEGER) DESC;
```

Comment: Hi Jorge, thank you so much. The problem was that my database settings showed: as "Varchar", I changed it to "Int" and it worked just fine. It's all sorted, thanks to you and everyone else who given their time to replay to my question. Anyone else who is struggling with this, the answer is: Make it to "INT" in Database settings. Thanks again Jorje :) and to everyone else as well <3

Answer (score 0):

I think it because of the reputation column in database is not int but varchar or text.

Answer (score 0):

if you change varchar to int then you will get the desired result.

Here's an example:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/830896/1

Answer (score 0):

You can Use CAST() function for types: BINARY, CHAR, DATE, DATETIME, TIME,DECIMAL, SIGNED, UNSIGNED

```
SELECT user_name, reputation FROM m_users ORDER BY  CAST(`reputation` AS UNSIGNED) DESC LIMIT 10
```